# CRM Dynamics Ribbon Workbench: FormStateRule for Active/Readonly screen not working

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, crm-ribbon-workbench

I have started working with the Ribbon Workbench for CRM Dynamics 365 and am having some problems. Specifically, I am need to hide a button if the form in question is Read Only and Active.

I've started by creating a DisplayRule that is assigned to the button in question. The DisplayRule consists of a FormStateRule with the following criteria

**Default**: False
**State**: ReadOnly
**InvertResult**: True

For some reason it isn't working. The button continues to display whether the Form is Read Only or not. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can get it to work? A requirement this simple shouldn't be this difficult to do!

I should add that I can make the DisplayRule toggle the button in general based on other criteria, it's this exact set of circumstances that I can't figure out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a vanilla button according to form state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48141180/how-to-hide-a-vanilla-button-according-to-form-state)

Comment: No, this isn't a duplicate of that issue. I've already verified that the button has been set to been Customized. I can also get the Display Rule to toggle based on other settings, such as setting the State to Create. I just can't seem to figure out how to tell when the state of the Form is ReadOnly despite there being an option for ReadOnly, which apparently doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Are you talking about CRM OOB read-only forms loaded for inactive records or disabling form controls some other means? Also checkout the InvertResult=false behavior.

Comment: No, this is a form that is in the Active state, but has also been set to ReadOnly in certain circumstances.

Comment: You may be setting it in form load script after ribbon loaded, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I was using a DisplayRule instead of an EnableRule. EnableRules provided me with a RecordPrivilegeRules. This provides the ability to determine the rights to the exact record in use as oppose to general access that you would get with a FormStateRule.

I'm a little mad at myself that it took so long to figure out something so simple, but hopefully this will help somebody else down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to use the below snippet to refresh the Ribbon controls, once you set your form to ReadOnly mode.

```
Xrm.Page.ui.refreshRibbon();
```

This is needed as you are loading ReadOnly form on certain circumstances, where the record is still active.